# Check if current bash script is running in background

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a script:

runner.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"

node --trace-warnings "$DIR/../engine/runner/Runner.js" "$@"
```

that I call that way:

```
./runner.sh --program --name=simple &
```

With or without `&` at the end of line. I'd like to detect that in `runner.sh` so I can run `node` in background or regular way.

How can we detect (in bash script) that script is running in background?

Comment: Being _in the background_ and being _a daemon_ are two different things.

Comment: A daemon, for example, won't have a TTY handle. That's easy to detect. But it's not true for just regular background processes.

Comment: Ah so I should ask instead how to detect that script is called in background

Comment: The _right way_ to run your program _as a daemon_ would be more like `./runner.sh --program --name=simple </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown -h $!` -- that way the program will keep running even if the window you started it from is closed. But yes, if you just want to detect being started in the background, that's different (and a little trickier).

Comment: In the linked duplicate, see in particular the answer by Gilles.